# Map fragment shows another wrong map fragment (one from the back stack) above it

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have one Activity and 4 fragments as follow.

Fragment A opens Fragment B (Has map fragment inside it along with other components).

Fragment B opens Fragment C

Fragment C opens Fragment D (Has map fragment inside it along with other components)

What's weird is that I see the map in fragment D and the other map from Fragment B above it.

```
<!-- Fragment B -->
 <LinearLayout .... 
   <fragment
            android:id="@+id/put_ad_google_map1"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/continue_button"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             />

<!-- Fragment D -->
<LinearLayout .... 

    <fragment
       android:id="@+id/put_ad_google_map2"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/continue_button"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        />
```

Any clue what the problem could be ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try `remove` the `map fragment` in Fragment B when start the Fragment C.

Sample code:

```
public void onDestroyView() 
{
        super.onDestroyView(); 
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I need the two Fragments together. I have map with markers, when marker clicks I open another detailed fragment with the map inside. When I click back, I should see the old fragment state as it is.

Comment: If you need two fragment, consider `add map fragment back`, and save the markers in `bundle or SQLite` or save in file

Comment: Yes this is the classic solution I think about. Problem of this is that it makes the app slower specially because I have large number of markers. Thanks again